# How to consolidate/extract repeated code structure in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

So many of my service methods follow this pattern:

```
  public async Task<ApiResponseDto> DoSomething(string parameter1, string parameter2) // differing parameters
    {
        try // repeated
        {
           using (var db = new DbContext()) // repeated
           {
             // do stuff - this is where the unique stuff is
           }   
        }
        catch(Exception e){ // repeated
           HandleServiceLayerException();
        } 
     }
```

Is there any way I can extract this out into a "footprint" so I don't have to repeat these ~10 lines for every service layer method?

Comment: have you considered using a function object wrapped around the core-functionality that is passed to a method invoking the wrapped function in the try-catch-statement?

Comment: @Benj that sounds awesome... do you have an example by any chance?

Comment: I will craft one. give me a second

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Func<DbContext, Task<ApiResponseDto>>`, for example:

```
public async Task<ApiResponseDto> DBHelper(Func<DbContext,Task<ApiResponseDto>> apiRes) // differing parameters
{
    try // repeated
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext()) // repeated
        {
            // do stuff - this is where the unique stuff is
            var result = await apiRes(db);
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { // repeated
        HandleServiceLayerException();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you can have a function defined like so:

```
public async Task<ApiResponseDto> DoDBStuff(DbContext db)
{
    // Do specific stuff
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
private async void Button_Click()
{
    await DBHelper(DoDBStuff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could easily use a `delegate` parameter in order to greatly simplify a lot of this code.

Say, for instance, that the only parameters you really needed were:

a.) the two strings (`parameter1` and `parameter2`), and

b.) the `DbContext`.

You could create the following delegate:

```
public delegate void DoSomethingDelegate(string parameter1, string parameter2, DbContext db);
```

Then, you can write a function with the same return value and parameters - for instance,

```
public void doSomethingSpecial(string parameter1, string parameter2, DbContext db)
{
   // do whatever you would do in the "special" part of your code.
}
```

And then, incorporate that into your method:

```
public async Task<ApiResponseDto> DoSomething(string parameter1, string parameter2, DoSomethingDelegate doMethod) // differing parameters
{
    try // repeated
    {
       using (var db = new DbContext()) // repeated
       {
         doMethod(parameter1, parameter2, db);
       }   
    }
    catch(Exception e){ // repeated
       HandleServiceLayerException();
    } 
 }
```

Then, just pass the method name into whatever call you have for `DoSomething`:

```
DoSomething(parameter1,parameter2, doSomethingSpecial);
```

Comment: Nice... what if I have different parameters/types for all of these methods?  Looking at this I feel like I'd have to create one delegate per signature, which leaves me kind of back at square one :(

Comment: Theoretically, you could do some encapsulation via something like `object`, but that's a route that gets a little messy and hard to keep track of. It's entirely possible, but I wouldn't necessarily recommend it. How varied would your parameters and return types be?

Comment: Very, unfortunately.  This is a service serving 100+ API controllers, so the signatures of each call are quite diverse.

Comment: @SB2055, there are generic delegates `Action<T1, T2, ...>` and `Func<TReturn, T1, T2, ...>` predefined for the range of 0 to 16 parameters.  This gets you down to 34 signatures.

Answer (score 1):

As promised - It is basically the same idea as proposed by Calmbit, but allows you to deal with any function signature, since you can pass the arguments in the function-object's constructor. The return value-type is passed when inheriting from the abstract class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflowSnippets
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DoSomething<Int32>(new CreateSumOf(30, 12)));
            Console.WriteLine(DoSomething<Int32>(new CreateDifferenceOf(30, 12)));
            Console.WriteLine(DoSomething<String>(new ConcatenateStrings("Function Objects ", "are cool")));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // This part can be considered the Framework and only has to be created once
        public static T DoSomething<T>(Function<T> f)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream dbContext = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    return f.ServiceImpl(dbContext);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // HandleServiceLayerException();
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        public abstract class Function<T>
        {
            public abstract T ServiceImpl(Stream /* DbContext */ dbContext);
        }

        // Then create one class for every ServiceFunction
        public class CreateSumOf : Function<Int32>
        {
            private Int32 _a;
            private Int32 _b;

            public CreateSumOf(Int32 a, Int32 b)
            {
                _a = a;
                _b = b;
            }

            public override Int32 ServiceImpl(Stream /*DbContext*/ dbContext)
            {
                return (_a + _b);
            }
        }
        public class CreateDifferenceOf : Function<Int32>
        {
            private Int32 _a;
            private Int32 _b;

            public CreateDifferenceOf(Int32 a, Int32 b)
            {
                _a = a;
                _b = b;
            }

            public override Int32 ServiceImpl(Stream /*DbContext*/ dbContext)
            {
                return (_a - _b);
            }
        }
        public class ConcatenateStrings : Function<String>
        {
            private String _a;
            private String _b;

            public ConcatenateStrings(String a, String b)
            {
                _a = a;
                _b = b;
            }

            public override String ServiceImpl(Stream /*DbContext*/ dbContext)
            {
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

                b.Append(_a); 
                b.Append(_b);

                return b.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

magically gives you

[image: The answer]